# No fonts in OpenJDK on headless CentOS 6 (for use in JasperReports)

Tags: java, fonts, jasper-reports

After upgrading JasperReports to 6.5.1 it was needed to upgrade Java to 1.8.0 (OpenJDK). Fonts were apparently not automatically installed and generating reports therefore produced a GUI initialization error. I manually copied the fonts from the previous Java version (1.7.0), errors went away and reports started to generate, but without any text. The text in the reports is given as 
`sansserif`, in fontconfig.properties.src it is mapped to `lucidasans-medium-r-normal-sans`, which has been copied.

This used to work on JasperReports 6.2.0 on Oracle Java 1.7.0, so I presume it must be a fonts configuration issue. Any ideas?

Comment: Use Oracle JDK instead of OpenJDK.

Answer (score 0):

sansserif is microsoft font it not install in centos by default 
try install font using  following commnad

```
 yum install curl cabextract xorg-x11-font-utils fontconfig
```